# Standard visitor visa uk

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, uk-citizens

I am a 16 year old boy from Albania and I would like to visit my cousin in England who is a British citizen. I have read some information on the uk goverment web page but I am a bit confused with the information. It says that I can visit a family member in UK with a standard visit visa but I don’t know if the word family member includes a cousin?
My cousin that lives there will also cover my expenses.
Please give me an answer if this kind of visa is suitable for me as a cousin of a British Citizen?

Comment: Information about Standard Visitor Visa I read at: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Comment: Standard visitor visa includes that, any family member, friends, business etc. Visiting a cousin would fall under the standard visitor visa category.

Comment: you may want to read this also https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18

Comment: @BritishSam Thank you for your quick answer but I am confused because for as much as I have read there it doesn’t say that with a standard visitor visa you can take a cousin

Comment: @Louis Anyone who is visiting the UK temporarily for leisure can use the Standard Visitor Visa. The reasons given are just examples.

Comment: Ok thank you. If I will have any other question I will ask you 

Comment: @MJeffryes I would make that an answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth how to make it as an answer

Comment: @Louis I meant that MJeffreyes should create an answer, using the information he put in the comment to create an answer.

Comment: @Louis they can't list every way you can use the visa, cousin counts as family, could even count as a friend, you're coming to visit someone, it falls under the standard visitor visa.

Answer (score 2):

You're not excluded from the Standard Visitor Visa even if you're a close relative of the person you're visiting.

This category is the one most people will use if they are not travelling to the UK for work/business or study. The use of "family" in the description is in my view, an attempt to make the text more understandable. It doesn't mean that you can only visit family. You can visit friends with whom you have no biological relationship, provided of course, you meet the relevant qualifications for the visa and are granted one.

I have had a few members of my extended family visit me using this route.